# Looking for a way to hide contents of a cell if other cells in the same row have values

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, counting

I'm pretty new at coding, by so far, I've gotten a long way with some results I'm happy with. However, I am stumped when it comes to formulas and scripting.

[image: Example of row]

As shown above, I have a record consisting of 11 columns. The first 10 columns are input data from a form I've made. The 11th column is a link generated from a script that would allow a user to re-enter information if they previously left it blank.

What I'm trying to do is find a way to hide the 11th column if and only if the other 10 columns have values contained in them.

I'm pretty sure a function or array is needed, but I do not know how to go about writing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Link to Project: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17H5Qi-OedED_ek1v5A5MLV9OWKEK-3Ku5vBvm9OqBdI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

try in K1:

```
={"Edit Link *"; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(IF(10=MMULT(IF(INDIRECT("A2:J"&COUNTA(A2:A)+1)="", 0, 1), 
 TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(A:J)^0)),,"generate link"))}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems like the array wont work as it would overwrite pulled data. Thanks though.